# Google Earth Engine Exported GeoTIFF is blank - how to export my code as an RGB for Ai or Ps

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, digital-image-processing, geemap

I am trying to export my classified map layer (classified_image) as a GeoTIFF, JPG or PNG (Any format that can be viewed on Illustrator or Photoshop). Geolocation does not matter, I just need the clean image.

Using export image to drive leads to a blank page. I have also tried thumbURL, image.visualize but still images come out blank. Please help

```
var selection = L8.filterBounds(ROI)
                  .filterDate("2002-01-01", "2002-12-01")
                  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 1)
                  .mean()
                  .clip(ROI)

Map.addLayer(selection, {bands:["B4", "B3", "B2"]})

var training_points = Water.merge(Vegetation).merge(Soil)
var training_data = selection.sampleRegions({
  collection: training_points, 
  properties: ['LT'],
  scale: 30
})

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart()

classifier = classifier.train({
  features: training_data,
  classProperty: "LT",
  inputProperties: ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"]
  })

var classified_image = selection.classify(classifier)
Map.addLayer(classified_image, {palette: ["0049bf", "07c46f", "ddd60b", "c91700"], min:0, max:3})

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified_RGB,
  description: 'RGBExample',
  scale: 30,
  region: ROI
});
```

Comment: `Image.visualize` is the correct tool for this — can you show us the version of your script that you tried with `Image.visualize` and doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I've updated to show the code I've written for Image.visualize (I am sure there is a mistake there, but haven't been able to figure it out yet)

Comment: Thanks! I don't see what the problem is if that's what you exported, though. But your code doesn't actually contain an `Export` call. I'd suggest you revise your question to contain _complete_ code that anyone can run in the Code Editor to get the same blank image you got.

Answer (score 0):

This self-answer resolves my question, with hekp from @KevinReid.
Everything was correct but it was missing a few parts.

Code includes an export to both link and drive options

```
var selection = L8.filterBounds(ROI)
                  .filterDate("2002-01-01", "2002-12-01")
                  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 1)
                  .mean()
                  .clip(ROI)

Map.addLayer(selection, {bands:["B4", "B3", "B2"]})

var training_points = Water.merge(Vegetation).merge(Soil)
var training_data = selection.sampleRegions({
  collection: training_points, 
  properties: ['LT'],
  scale: 30
})

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart()

classifier = classifier.train({
  features: training_data,
  classProperty: "LT",
  inputProperties: ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"]
  })

var classified_image = selection.classify(classifier)
Map.addLayer(classified_image, {palette: ["0049bf", "07c46f", "ddd60b", "c91700"], min:0, max:3})
   var image_RGB = selection.visualize({'bands': ["B4", "B3", "B2"], max:0.5});   
    var classified_RGB= classified_image.visualize ({ 
      'min':0,
      'max':2,
      'palette': ['0049bf', '07c46f', 'c91700', 'ddd60b']
      
    }); 
    
    print(classified_RGB.getThumbURL({region:ROI, scale:200, min:0, max:3000, format:'jpg'})); 

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified_RGB,
  description: 'RGBExample',
  scale: 30,
  region: ROI
});
```